# Does chi-square with N degrees of freedom stochastically dominate chi-square with M degrees of freedom whenever N>M?

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, chi-squared-distribution, stochastic-dominance

Does chi-square with N degrees of freedom stochastically dominate chi-square with M degrees of freedom whenever N>M?

My guess is yes. As $\chi^2_{N}=\sum_{i=1}^NZ_i^2$ and  $\chi^2_{M}=\sum_{i=1}^M Y_i^2$, where $Y_i,Z_i$ are standard normal distributions. It seems that $Pr(\chi^2_{N}<x)=Pr(\sum_{i=1}^NZ_i^2<x)\leq Pr(\sum_{i=1}^M Y_i^2<x)=Pr(\chi^2_{M}<x)$. Intuitively, chi-square with N degrees of freedom has more nonnegative numbers of the same distribution added up together, and it's less likely to be small compared to one with M(M<N) degrees of freedom.  Does this look correct?

Comment: Clearly everything is non-negative (sums of squares) and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^NZ_i^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^M Z_i^2 +\sum\limits_{i=M+1}^N Z_i^2 \ge \sum\limits_{i=1}^M Z_i^2 $ so $\mathbb P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^NZ_i^2 <x\right) \le \mathbb P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^MZ_i^2 <x\right) $

Comment: @Henry Right! Thanks.